# Python can't consistently find a module while the parent directory is in sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a project where I need to import self made modules that could be anywhere on the filesystem. But python can't seem to consistently import them.

All the modules have the same name which is why I couple them with their parent directory, like so : `xyz.abc` for a module called `abc.py` in a folder called `xyz`. xyz's parent directory is added to path. To import them later on, I use `importlib.import_module(module_name)` where module name is `xyz.abc`.

To test my code, I am using python's tempfile lib to create temporary directories and temporary files. (`/tmp` on my system is cleaned at reboot and not automatically.)

I've tried adding an `__init__.py` file, it doesn't change anything.
I've also tried `os.sync()` to force write the file to my disk thinking it might be a race problem but it didn't help.

Here's the code where it breaks:

```
if parent not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, parent)
module_name = os.path.basename(dir_path) + "." + filename.split(".")[0]
return importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

The tree structure of the directory is :

```
/tmp/tmp9tp_1j_q/
└── tmprvbxhk3t.py
```

And `sys.path` has `'/tmp'` in it when I print it right before `module_name = ...`.

When executing the code, **sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't**. I get:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tmpfjig62pf'`

I'm thinking maybe `sys.path` isn't internally updated directly after an insert.

I need some help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't in `sys.path`, but it's close.
 It is the Finder object in `sys.meta_path` that uses `sys.path` and `sys.path_hooks` to look for modules, and `sys.meta_path` has internal caches that aren't "refreshed" automatically in such a situation.

So, to successfully import a module that's been created after the interpreter began execution, the internal caches of `sys.meta_path` should be invalidated.

That can be achieved by calling `importlib.invalidate_caches()` after creating the test modules.